# Migrating VS2008 to VS2015 Linker Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008

We are in the midst of migrating VS2008 code to VS2015
One of the key error is the error message in the MAS_COMMON File
Will appreciate any insights on how we can resolve this:
[library link error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Yr1.png)

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 does not define the __iob_func object that you're looking for, while VS2008 did.  The library you're linking against is old and requires it.  Best to define it yourself.

Add the following to one of your source files in the affected project and it may help it link.

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1900  // VS2015+

static FILE iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };

extern "C" FILE* __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return iob;
}

#endif // _MSC_VER
```